# How to search for Facebook Open Graph actions on an a self hosted object

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We have custom Open Graph object and action. How to find the action and object id from the object url.
I tried with `https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://test.azumio-com.appspot.com/shared/ts2/619043781` but it does not return the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `object_url` table

`SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url="http://test.azumio-com.appspot.com/shared/ts2/619043781"`

Comment: This does return an id but it's not the id of the action posted.

Comment: @phubar It shouldn't an action id is associated with a user. This is the object id.

Comment: actions are on object, i want to know which action are on a particular object. In our case object are user owned and there is always one action per object.